# Image not stored on the server public folder

Tags: html, database, laravel

I build a form that contain image upload. It shows no eror, but the image is not stored on the server. Only the path that I create stored on the database.
Here is my blade:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Photo</label>
  <input name="photo" type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
</div>
```

And this is the method I'm using to store the image:

```
$file = $request->file('photo');
    $nama = $request->name;

                  $judul_image = $nama;
                  $extension      = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                  $namax          = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                  $directory      = public_path().'/images/speakers/';
                  $filename       = $judul_image.'-'.$namax;
                  $path           = $file->getPathName();
                  $upload_success = $file->move($directory, $filename);

                  $imgurl = 'http://indoebtkeconex.com/images/speakers/'.$filename;
    $speakers = new Speakers;
    $speakers->name = $nama;
    $speakers->position = $request->position;
    $speakers->photo = $imgurl;
    $speakers->year = 2019;
    $speakers->save();
```

the $imgurl saved properly on the database, but the image not stored on the server. Is there anything missing here?

Comment: Does it work on local and not on production?

Comment: Have you setup the storage link. `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: did you set the form to ```enctype='multipart/form-data'```?

Comment: I'm working on production server, haven't tried on local.

Comment: No, I haven't setup the storage link. Is it important? Because I haven't seen any tutorials that using the storage link

Comment: yes. I've already set the enctype form